# Bundler:HTTPError Could not download gem sidekiq-pro-5.3.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, sidekiq, sidekiq-pro

Bundler:HTTPError Could not download gem sidekiq-pro-5.3.0. I am unable to install the sidekiq pro gem for rails due to a permissions error.

`$ bundle install`

```
Bundler::HTTPError: Could not download gem from https://gems.contribsys.com/ due to underlying error <bad response Unauthorized 401
(https://gems.contribsys.com/gems/sidekiq-pro-5.3.0.gem)>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a FAQ covering how to debug this issue.

https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Commercial-FAQ#how-do-i-debug-a-401-access-denied-error

Comment: The man himself. Thanks bro you're my hero.

Answer (score 1):

Lacked credentials in bundle config.

`$ bundle config --local gems.contribsys.com user:password`
with the proper values sets a line in the `.bundle/config` which looks like

```
---
BUNDLE_GEMS__CONTRIBSYS__COM: "user:password"
```

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler-configuration was a helpful source of information.

installing sidekiq pro completed properly after that.